# Rails 3 Jquery Doesn't Execute After Deleting Public/Assets

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, asset-pipeline

I was running into some Ajax problems the other day where forms were submitted multiple times with the click of a submit button. I did some browsing around and somebody recommended that I delete my public/assets folder, I did so and restarted my server only to find that some of my Javascript libraries were no longer functioning correctly...

<s>It's actually very strange because I can look at the source code with Firebug debugger and I can see that it definitely loaded. I tried to clear my cache, I tried to procompile my assets in development mode, I tried a fresh restart of my system, none of these things worked. My Javascript simply isn't running and fails silently after deleting my public/assets folder.</s>     - **see edit**

*Quick reference of how I produced this issue:*

1. **Stopped server**
2. **Deleted public/assets**
3. **Restarted server and noticed issue**
4. **Cleared cache**
5. **Stopped server again and attempted to pre-compile assets**

*Additional things I've tried:*

1. **Set `config.serve_static_assets = false` in development.rb, pre-compile again and restarted server**
2. **Verified that I was running in development mode via rails s -e development**
3. **Deleted my tmp/cache folder**

*Extra information:*

- **I'm using Rails version 3.1.3**
- **I recently started using a Gem that required me to set config.cache_classes to true in development. I verified that this wasn't the problem by setting it to false and re-testing.**

**Edit**

Further testing has show that my changes prevented the following code from ever triggering:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     alert("Hello world!")
   });

</script>
```

But this works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Hello world!")
</script>
```

Initially I thought that files weren't being loaded from my Asset pipeline, but instead it looks like my changes caused some kind of conflict behind the scenes. I removed `require_tree` from my application.js file and attempted to load libraries manually to find that they began to work again, this isn't an ideal fix for me.

Comment: It seems that something has caused my `jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{...});` functions to not fire....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit, two birds with one stone actually. One of my JavaScript files were requiring both jquery and jquery_ujs for a second time when it was already being required in my application.js file which was the cause of my mentioned Ajax problem. The very same file was running script that wasn't enclosed with the jquery document ready wrapper which seemed to have broken everything else.

I believe the problem only presented itself after I deleted my public/assets folder because it was storing an older version of this code which possibly didn't have these challenges.